# FTP vs SFTP, this time- stability

Tags: unix, ftp, sftp, robustness, stability

I have read a great post regarding the FTP/SFTP speeds: [Why when I transfer a file through SFTP, it takes longer than FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849240/why-when-i-transfer-a-file-through-sftp-it-takes-longer-than-ftp)

But did anyone check, or have a proof or documents,tests showing which of these two is more **'stable'** when transferring files (thousands of small files, and couple huge files)?

Which protocol (SFTP, FTP) using native client/server (Unix) is more/less likely to drop the connections or be able to reconnect or even detect stalled connection, and is less probable to mess up the files

Comment: Is someone in the middle running off with a copy of your files part of the category of stable?

Comment: might be if thats the only pro/con :)

Comment: What inspired you to do secure anyway?

Comment: Not a good programming question - should be on  superuser.com.  The answer is : neither one.  Use a tool like rsync if you want that kind of surety in file transfers.  Or. checksum each file first locally, then get a checksum on the other side.  Compare the checksums.  cksum, md5 are probably okay for something like this.

Comment: here is example/strace: recently one of my boxes encountered following problem when connecting to some FTP servers .Connection got hung at this stage: write(3, "USER testtest\r\n", 21) = 21.

And this keeps happening on daily basis, when trying to connect to multiple clients.
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x40e780, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fe019f3b6e0}, {0x40e780, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fe019f3b6e0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x40e6f0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fe019f3b6e0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fe019f3b6e0}, 8) = 0
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={60, 0}, it_value={60, 0}}, NULL) = 0
read(3,